# Pulseaudio antidetects headphones

Tags: pulseaudio

When I plug in my headphones I get the following Output Devices in `pavucontrol`:

```
Speakers
Analog Output
Headphones (unplugged)
```

Choosing Speakers sends output to Speakers+Headphones.

Choosing Analog Output or Headphones (unplugged) send output to Headphones only.

If I unplug the headphones I get:

```
Speakers (unavailable)
Analog Output
Headphones (plugged in)
```

No matter what I choose I get no audio.

It seems PulseAudio is confused by my headphones: Unplugging my headphones does not cause my speakers to vanish into thin air.

How can I tell PulseAudio:

- My speakers are here to stay. They will never be unavailable.
- My headphones are plugged in when you think they are not and vice versa.

Output from `pulseaudio -vvvv` when unplugging headphones:

```
D: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Jack 'Front Mic Jack' is now unplugged
D: [pulseaudio] device-port.c: Setting port analog-input-microphone-front to status no
D: [pulseaudio] device-port.c: Setting port analog-input-microphone-internal to status unknown
D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
D: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Jack 'Front Headphone Jack' is now plugged in
D: [pulseaudio] device-port.c: Setting port analog-output-speaker to status no
D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
D: [pulseaudio] device-port.c: Setting port analog-output-headphones to status yes
D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
```

When plugging in headphones:

```
D: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Jack 'Front Mic Jack' is now plugged in
D: [pulseaudio] device-port.c: Setting port analog-input-microphone-front to status yes
D: [pulseaudio] device-port.c: Setting port analog-input-microphone-internal to status no
D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
D: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Jack 'Front Headphone Jack' is now unplugged
D: [pulseaudio] device-port.c: Setting port analog-output-speaker to status unknown
D: [pulseaudio] device-port.c: Setting port analog-output-headphones to status no
D: [pulseaudio] core-subscribe.c: Dropped redundant event due to change event.
```

The above leads me to believe that there is missing a "not" somewhere in 'module-alsa-card.c' and that it somehow feels the headphone port is also a mic port.

Comment: You'll want to map the channels to the correct i/o plugs, I think. I'm pretty sure [this](http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=24148) is what I used to do rear/front swaps for surround... At a lower level you may need to do something along the same lines for ALSA. You won't get an answer here from me - I consider the whole computer/A/V frontier a magical world of wonder and am just happy to sometimes get a glimpse - I never understand it, though.

Comment: It looks like the headphone jack sense signal doesn't work the way the driver expects, but just the opposite way. This would be a pretty typical hardware-model-specific quirk: [see the first post of this thread in the Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1043568): there is a long list of system models that have needed non-default audio configuration. If your model is not one of those, you might try the options intended for other models from the same manufacturer.